# Changing WHERE clause based on input parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to change the `WHERE` clause of a query based upon the value of an input parameter.

I'm guessing this is possible, but it seems that I'm approaching it in the wrong way?

A simplified version of my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleProc]
    @appId INT,
    @siteId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM T_Mytable m
    WHERE
        CASE  
           WHEN @siteId = '0' THEN m.appId = @appId
           ELSE m.appId = @AppId AND m.siteId = @siteId
        END
END
```

How to achieve this `WHERE` clause.  I cannot do an assignment in the `CASE` expression in `WHERE`.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding the `SELECT *` as a general rule. If the table structure changes, so will the result of your stored procedure, and you may not want that.

Comment: that was given just an example...my query is mainly to handle the where condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because both your cases share the `m.appId = @appId` condition, you may refactor your `WHERE` logic as:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM T_Mytable m
WHERE
    m.appId = @appId AND
    @siteId IN (0, m.siteId);
```

`CASE` expressions are designed to generate literal values, not logical expressions, as their output.  So, putting a `CASE` expression into the `WHERE` clause as you have done it does not make sense.  Instead, just write the conditions using `AND` plus `OR` directly.

Comment: You might also want to throw in a word about the unnecessary implicit conversion of `'0'` to `0`, while you're at it :-).

Comment: but I dont have value '0' for siteid in table. This is some input parameter with indication can I have to pick all sites for a particular appid.. Hence I want that in where conditon

Comment: Tim is **not** checking `m.siteId = 0`. He is checking `@siteId = 0`. Do note the `@` in the `@siteId IN (0, m.siteId)`